# Is there a tool for showing trend in a technical research field?

Tags: publications, bibliometrics, tools

Does anyone know if there exists a tool to generate the trend of interest in a particular research field over time?

I am particularly interested in wearable computing. I know this field has been hot for the last few years, I would like a measure of this “hotness” using academic publications relating to this area. i.e. the number of publications related to the keyword *Wearable Computing.*

Is there a tool that shows the trend of publications in an particular topic similar to how Google keeps track of keywords that people searches for?

[image]

Note: I am specifically interested in technical research field, such that papers that would get published in IEEE or some computer science journals.

Comment: Related: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3439/easy-way-to-see-historical-trend-in-keywords-in-publications

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use [Scopus](http://www.scopus.com/) quite a lot and it provides the ability to analyze keywords (there is a link to 'Analyze search results'):
[image]

I was able to quickly obtain this plot for publications per year for the keyword 'wearable computing':

[image]

It can also be restricted to particular sources. For example
this one for 'wearable computing' in 'IEEE Pervasive computing':

[image]

Unfortunately you need a subscription to access Scopus.

Comment: Hey thanks my university has a subscription to it!

Answer (score 2):

It's not a tech-heavy corpus, but JSTOR's DFR does exactly what you want for the JSTOR collection.

http://dfr.jstor.org/?cs=any%3Awearable+&fs=ktm1&view=chart

[image: JSTOR DFR]